# spring boot dependency Injection with @Cacheable in kotlin, will makes the variable null passed by the superclass super

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, cglib

In kotlin, when I use this way, let bean test2 pass to test3, when I Inject test1, and call `test()` function, it will get null result when I print test2.

```kotlin
@Service
class Test1(test2: Test2) : Test3(test2) {
    @Cacheable(value = ["cacheKey"], key = "#key")
    fun cache(key: String): String {
        return ""
    }
}

@Service
class Test2 {
}

open class Test3(val test2: Test2) {
    fun test() {
        println(test2)
    }
}
```

but in java, there is no such problem.

```java
@Service
public class JTest1 extends JTest3 {
    public JTest1(JTest2 JTest2) {
        super(JTest2);
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "cacheKey", key = "#key")
    public String cache(String key) {
        return "";
    }
}

@Service
public class JTest2 {
}

public class JTest3 {
    private final JTest2 JTest2;

    public JTest3(JTest2 JTest2) {
        this.JTest2 = JTest2;
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println(JTest2);
    }

}
```

I decompiled kotlin bytecode, it dose it looks like java class decompiled.

I already figure it out this kotlin issue reason is `@Cacheable` annotation, it will let spring boot proxy it with cglib.

But I want to known, why only appear in kotlin, what caused the issuse.